# Add onclick to a dynamically create li tag

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to add an onclick handler to a dynamically created div.

Here is how I create the elements:

```
function add_remove_roll_func(){
    for (var i = 0; i<3; i++){
    li_dice_side_one = createElementWithClass('li',arguments[i]);
    add_remove_roll.appendChild(li_dice_side_one);
    document.getElementById("ul");
  }
    }
 add_remove_roll = createElementWithOutClass('ul');
    dice_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(add_remove_roll);
    document.getElementById("dice-content-wrapper");

    add_remove_roll_func("add","remove","roll");
```

I want the add remove and roll events to call different functions.

I tried doing `add_remove_roll_func("'add' 'onclick="function'...)`
But that did not auto-magically work :).

I could do it with jQuery but I need to do this with native javascript.

Comment: What are `createElementWithClass` and `createElementWithOutClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is add_remove_roll_func?!

You need to use addEventListener() in order to add onclick or any other handler to an event. Example:

```
el.addEventListener("click", liCliked, false); 

function liCliked(){
    // doing important things
}
```